# How to undeploy the network on composer network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am using composer v.0.20.8 currently
and I keep updating my .bna file.
but every time I generate a new .bna file I have to teardown my fabric network and redeploy it.

Is there a way where I can just deploy it without tearing down my network in v.0.20.8 Composer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer provides a upgrade utility to do just that. Please see the below link for reference.

[Upgrading a business network](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/composer.network.upgrade.html)

Let us know if you get stuck in the process.

Comment: Thanks, It Worked Really Well!